# Asp.Net 5 json configuration encrypt database connectionstring

Tags: asp.net5

What is the best way to encrypt connectionstring in appsettings.json file (settings configuration file). Is there a tool for that or we have to do it manually?

Note: Connecting to SQL Server and SQL Azure. This is hosted as an Azure website.

Comment: Are you connecting to MS SQL Server? You might want to consider using SSPI instead - this is when the connection-string does not need to contain a password.

Comment: Note that encrypting the connection string doesn't actually solve a security hole: because now you have the problem of needing somewhere to securely store the decryption key for the connection string.

Comment: I always using RSA to encrypt database connection string. You can read more at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650304.aspx

Comment: @Dai - It's SQL server and SQL Azure (in staging and prod). Do you have any reference on how to do it? It came as a quick requirement and looking for a quick solution if available.

Comment: @Van - Mate, in asp.net 5 I am not using a web.config. That's what I used to do. I need a way to encrypt the json configuration.

Comment: I also am trying to figure out how to do this.   @Dhanuka777, did you ever get a resolution?

Comment: @Brian, answer is no, could not find a proper way to do it. What I did was, I stored the connection string in Azure Website (Azure App service) in "application settings" which overrides the conn string.